# Enable sharing of a folder and copy pasting between a Mac and a virtual machine

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I want to enable sharing between my Mac and a virtual machine running Ubuntu image, and I see [one way is to enable sharing of the folders](https://medium.com/macoclock/share-folder-between-macos-and-ubuntu-4ce84fb5c1ad) but I keep seeing `wrong fs type bad option bad superblock` error.

I tried the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964944/i-cannot-mount-the-shared-folder-between-host-windows-machine-and-virtualbox-gue) but it was `unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-utils`.

In addition, how else do you enable copy/pasting between a Mac and a virtual machine?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691803/how-to-install-guest-addition-in-mac-os-as-guest-and-windows-machine-as-host might point in the right direction - but nix can't read APFS natively.

Comment: oh, of course, nor HFS.

Comment: I'm confused...

Comment: By what, specifically?